# How would I give the choice to do multiple math problems without having to copy and paste the code each time?

Tags: c++

My code allows for the user to either input some numbers or read them from a document. How would I also allow the user to pick from a choice of math problems to perform on those numbers without having a bunch of code in my main.
Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //ask for file input or manual input
    cout << "Press 1 to enter numbers or 2 to read them from a list." << "\n";
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        int numberswanted;
        cout << "How many numbers would you like to enter?" << "\n";
        cin >> numberswanted;

        vector<double> list;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberswanted; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter your numbers: " << "\n";
            double x;
            cin >> x;
            list.push_back(x);
        }

    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        ifstream doc;
        float output;
        doc.open("input.txt");
        while (!doc.eof())
        {
            vector<double> list;
            double x;
            doc >> x;
            list.push_back(x);
        }
        doc.close();

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you're asking how to move code out of the `main()` function and into other structures?  What you're looking for are things like `methods` and `classes`.

Comment: If you're duplicating code, move the duplicated code into a separate function.   Call that function instead of duplicating code.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try something like this :

```
int main() { cout << "Press 1 to enter numbers or 2 to read them from a list." << "\n";
int choice;
cin >> choice;

if (choice == 1)
{
    choice1();

}
else if (choice == 2)
{
    choice2();

}
return 0;}
```

when `choice1` contains `int [...] list.push_back(x);}`
etc...

Comment: Common technique is to use `switch` for processing menu items rather than an `if-else` ladder.

Comment: dude in first time i was to recomand him to use some proper ways and design patterns, and ended copying his code.